# Why does my program's control flow seem to jump around when stepping through a factorial method?

Tags: c#, factorial

I am studying C# on my own and was curious how a simple code runs.

I inserted a linebreak on the `if` statement and stepped into it line by line. I want to know why the code keeps coming back to the curly brace above the `if` statement when you run the code after the compiler knows the if statement is false? It doesn't return the result from the else statement just yet until the `if` statement is `true`; and when it does, it goes back and forth into the else statement adding 1 to the `num` value to perform the factorial.

Can anyone explain it to me better?

```
namespace Factorial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NumberManipulator manipulator = new NumberManipulator();
            Console.WriteLine("Factorial of six is :" + manipulator.factorial(6));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class NumberManipulator
    {
        public int factorial(int num)
        {
            int result;
            if (num == 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                result = factorial(num - 1) * num;
                return result;
            }
        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: it might be better to handle while condition!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is recursive, so it will call itself.

When you call `factorial(6)` to calculate `6*5*4*3*2*1`, it will in turn call `factorial(5)` to calculate the part `5*4*3*2*1` and multiply that with `6`.

The call to `factorial(5)` will in turn call `factorial(4)` to calculate `4*3*2*1` and multiply that with `5`.

So it will keep calling itself until the call is `factorial(1)` and the first part of the `if` statement ends the recursion.

When you single step through the code you will se the execution jump to the start of the method for each call deeper, until you get to the innermost call where it will start returning from all the calls. If you watch the call stack, you will see that it grows with each level of recursion, then shrinks again.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps it is just weird to me how a computer decides to compute and all. Its like it only subtracted 1 from 6 first until the if statement is true then it decides to multiply after that when i step into it line by line :)

Comment: @Airynd: Yes, there is no multiplication going on at all until it reaches the innermost call and `return 1` returns the `1` part of the calculation. When that is returned it is multiplied by `2` and the result is returned to the next lower level to be multiplied by `3` and so on.

Comment: @Airynd to be clear, its not how computer decided.. it is how we program it to do stuff for us.. For example, factorial is a simple case, where one could have easily implemented it with a for loop (no recursion). In that case, you'd indeed see numbers getting multiplied in a loop.. I am guessing that you were trying out this code from somewhere else (factorial is a good / simple way to teach recursion).. As an exercise, try writing factorial as a normal, non-recursive function.. Should be easier :) Good Luck :D

Comment: @Guffa I see...does the computer kinda remembers the last value of a variable like in a stack of cards in a recursion? and will only do the other operations when the recursion ends, like in this example?

Comment: @VikasGupta yeah i'm trying to understand how recursion works.. thanks to both of you for the help :D

Comment: @Airynd Note how you call `manipulator.factorial(6));` from your `Main` function. From computers point of view, there is no difference in how `Main` calls `factorial` vs how `factorial` calls `factorial`. In fact, in `call stack window` you'd find Main at the `bottom` (which is **not** the whole truth). Recursion is a technique easily implemented in computer programs. again, from computers perspective, there is no difference. Yes, it kinda remembers where it left the previous function, and in what state, when another function is called. Stack is most common way of implementing it.

Comment: @Airynd: Yes, the local variables are allocated on the stack, so each call to the method has its own set of local variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int factorial(int num)
{
....
    result = factorial(num - 1) * num;
....
```

Notice how the function factorial, calls itself, although with a smaller number with each call.
This is called recursion, and is an important and useful way to solve many problems in programming.

The important aspect of recursion is that it must end, otherwise you go in infinite loop, and blow up your code with `StackOverflowException` (what a coincidence, this site is called StackOverflow :))

The following code ends the recursion..

```
if (num == 1)
{
    return 1;
}
```

You can also turn the `call stack window` on, while debugging, and observe how same function is calling itself with a growing stack (reason for the jump back to top of the function).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code, it works and has been tested! Two methods are implemented: **Recursive** and **Basic** factorial calculation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication50
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        NumberManipulator manipulator = new NumberManipulator();
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Factorial Number:");
        int a= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("---Basic Calling--");
        Console.WriteLine("Factorial of {0} is: {1}" ,a, manipulator.factorial(a));

        Console.WriteLine("--Recursively Calling--");
        Console.WriteLine("Factorial of {0} is: {1}", a, manipulator.recursively(a));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class NumberManipulator
{
    public int factorial(int num)
    {
        int result=1;
        int b = 1;
        do
        {
            result = result * b;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            b++;
        } while (num >= b);
        return result;
    }

    public int recursively(int num)
    {
        if (num <= 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return recursively(num - 1) * num;
        }
    }
  }
}
```